# docker-compose: multiple images per service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create two dockers: one nginx and the other nodejs. However, I find two sets of images are being created. I have deleted all existing images and rebooted the system, yet it shows as below. The relevant files are below.

The following is the docker-compose.yml

```
services:

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - node:node

  node:
    build: ./node
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./node:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

The nginx Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

And the NodeJS Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM node:9.3.0-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The `docker images` command shows:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hudddle_nginx       latest              f784ac4611f5        5 minutes ago       108MB
hudddle_node        latest              5e083ec259e7        5 minutes ago       70.4MB
node                9.3.0-alpine        466bcf8bf36e        3 days ago          67.6MB
nginx               latest              f895b3fb9e30        5 days ago          108MB
```

Why is it so? The Server (AWS) was created today. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats the correct behaviour

As you using FROM nginx and FROM node in dockerfile, while building docker gets nginz and node images from dockerhub.

So when you want to  build docker again , this time it will not download from dockerhub instead it uses local cached image.

Maybe you using below commands to build

```
docker build -t hudddle_nginx .
docker build -t hudddle_node .
```

Because of that its base images first nginx and node and then your custom images hudddle_nginx,hudddle_node

Comment: thanks for the response @sanath-meti. I am not using the build command. But does it mean that there are two images. And what would the 3 days ago mean? Does docker-hub have a copy of my settings?

Comment: how did you got these images hudddle_nginx ?, when you run build command using dockerfiel it created this hudddle_nginx and as you using FROM nginx in dockerfile so it downloaded that image and the one hudddle_nginx which you mentioned while building, 3day ago means someone made commit for that image in dockerhub repo.

Comment: To make a **commit** for that image in docker repo, don't we need to have a login or some sort? While I tested I could have used the build command but on the current new server I used the `docker-compose`. Is there a way to find out if hudddle_nginx exists in docker-hub? I tried searching and it shows null.

Comment: you can create the dockerhub repo , it provides one free private repo, and then you can push the image to docker repo.

Comment: Thanks. Will do that